# how can I add subtitles using shaka-player from a .mpd file?

Tags: streaming, subtitle, shaka, video-subtitles

I'm using the shaka player with the below build.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/3.0.8/shaka-player.compiled.js

I'm using a .mpd file and it has a subtitle file.

```
<AdaptationSet contentType="text" mimeType="text/vtt" lang="en" group="3" label="English">
      <Label>English</Label>
      <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle" />
      <Representation bandwidth="1732" id="7">
        <BaseURL>cmaf/subtitle-en.vtt</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
```

I want to display the subtitles in my video player. How can I configure the player to identify the subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

with ,

```
player.setTextTrackVisibility(true);
```

We can display subtitles of one language.